# Messaging Objective-C method from C++ method?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I'm reading this article about creating a global hotkey. I've gone through the tutorial successfully, but now I'm trying to message an Objective-C method, and I'm stuck. Is there a way to message Objective-C from C++ code?

http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/03/global-keyboard-shortcuts-with-carbon.html

Here's where my code is at:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize statusItem;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    EventHotKeyRef myHotKeyRef;
    EventHotKeyID myHotKeyID;
    EventTypeSpec keyPressedEventType;
    EventTypeSpec keyReleaseEventType;

    keyPressedEventType.eventClass=kEventClassKeyboard;
    keyPressedEventType.eventKind=kEventHotKeyPressed;

    keyReleaseEventType.eventClass=kEventClassKeyboard;
    keyReleaseEventType.eventKind=kEventHotKeyReleased;

    InstallApplicationEventHandler(&keyPressedHandler, 1, &keyPressedEventType, NULL, NULL);
    InstallApplicationEventHandler(&keyReleasedHandler, 1, &keyReleaseEventType, NULL, NULL);

    myHotKeyID.signature='mhk1';
    myHotKeyID.id=1;

    RegisterEventHotKey(97, 0, myHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &myHotKeyRef);
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"microphone_muted"]];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"neg_microphone_muted"]];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}
- (void) mute
{
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"microphone_muted"]];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"neg_microphone_muted"]];
}
- (void) unmute 
{
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"microphone"]];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"neg_microphone"]];
}
OSStatus keyPressedHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef anEvent, void *userData)
{   
    NSLog(@"Unmute mic");
    return noErr; 
}
OSStatus keyReleasedHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef anEvent, void *userData)
{
    NSLog(@"Mute mic");
    return noErr; 
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your C++ source files have the extension `.mm` (instead of `.cpp`), then it will be compiled as Objective-C++, and you will be able send messages to your Objective-C objects just as if you were using a standard `.m` source file.

Comment: I may have phrased my question incorrectly. My intention was to somehow reference the app delegate inside the C++ method so I could message the mute method from inside keyPressedHandler. It turns out I had to send a reference through the userData parameter of the InstallApplicationEventHandler method.

Comment: I did end up renaming the file to .mm (since that's the convention) although I noticed I was able to use Objective-C syntax inside the C++ function while still keeping the .m extension. I was using the latest Xcode 4. This is all one file, btw.

Answer (score 1):

No need to even change the file extension.  Just do RMB/"show info" or whatever on your C++ file and change the type from "cpp" to "objective_c/cpp" or whatever (I forget what the actual values are).

Then you can intermix C++ and Objective-C to your heart's content.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Following the naming conventions solves the problem, and anyone looking at your project will be able to tell that a .mm file is going to be compiled as Objective-C++  without having to hunt it down.

Comment: If the file is mostly C++, with only a smattering of Objective-C, then it makes more sense to label it C++.  (And even Xcode labels `main` as C, although it contains Objective-C.)

Comment: Except that once you introduce Objective-C to the source, it is no longer just C/C++. The technique you describe is useful, and in some circumstances, good enough, but a majority of the time it is best to stick with using non-contradictory naming convention.